# "Шевелюра" — от слова "шевелить"?

Tags: этимология

Шевелюра - это буйная прическа, густые волосы. Но почему — шевелюра? Слово ведь образовано от "шевелить", да?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шевелюра от франц. chevelure - то же от сhеvеu "волос".

Латинское – capillus (волосы).
Слово «шевелюра» было заимствовано из французского языка в начале XIX в.
Так называют густые, буйно разросшиеся волосы. Вообще, слово «шевелюра» само по себе является производным, носящим собирательное значение (ср. «профессор» – «профессура»).
Предполагается, что первоисточником является латинское слово capillus – «волосы на голове», «борода». (Этимол. словарь р. яз. Семенова)

У Фасмера:  ШЕВЕЛИТЬ 
 Ближайшая этимология: укр. шевелiти "шелестеть", блр. шаволiць "шевелить, шарить, рыться", болг. шавам "двигаю", чеш. «eveliti "шуметь", слвц. «еvеlit' "шуршать, свистеть", нж.-луж. «awlis "бродить, шататься" и др.
Дальнейшая этимология: Сравнивают с др.-инд. "двигается", "приходить в движение" (Младенов 690), а также с гот.  "странствовать", др.-исл.  "двигать", лат.  "качаться"...

ШЕВЕЛЮРА по Фасмеру от французского. Но есть пометка, что народная этимология сближает с предыдущим словом (т.е. с "шевелить")

Получается, что слова исконно совсем разные, но люди часто их воспринимают как близкие в виду сходства. Есть даже "от страха волосы шевелятся".

Comment: >укр. шевелiти "шелестеть"

Ответ интересный, от меня +1.
Но... вот этого "шевелiти" мне не приходилось встречать. Да ещё и в значении "шелестеть", а не "шевелить". Может быть кто-то из участников форума такое встречал? Бывают разные говоры. 

"Шелестеть" на Украине это обычно "шарудIти". Или могут сказать с тем же корнем "шелест", т.е. "шелестIти".

Comment: В словаре Фасмера так написано. Мой "переводчик" такого слова не знает. "Шевелить" переводит как "ворушити", а "шелестеть" - "шелестiти". Спрошу у кого-нибудь из носителей

Comment: Я, признаться, тоже не слышала, чтобы "шевелiти" переводилось как "шелестеть". Так что, согласна с Nikolja